# CreateJS - d.mousedown.f error on hitAreas

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

While programming in CreateJS I have encountered a bug:

> Unhandled exception at line 13, column 10113 in https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2014.12.12.min.js
>
> 0x800a138f - Runtime Error JavaScript code: Can not retrieve "matrix" properties for undefined or empty appeal

This bug appears only when I add a hit area into an image:

```
    function drawButton(e) {
        var button = new createjs.Bitmap(e.target);
        var newContainer = new createjs.Container();
        newContainer.addChild(button);
        var label = new createjs.Text("Next round", "20 px Arial", "#000");
        newContainer.addChild(label);
        button.hitArea = new createjs.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        button.addEventListener("click", onClick);
        buttonContainer.addChild(newContainer);

        GameData.hudStage.update();
    }
```

After removing: **button.hitArea = new createjs.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);** the bug does not appear. Is it a a library bug, or did I something miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hitArea` has to be a `DisplayObject` - but you're trying to assign a `Rectangle` as a `hitArea`, which isn't a `DisplayObject`. If you use a `Shape` (or so) the code should work as expected:

```
 var shape = new createjs.Shape();
 shape.graphics.beginFill("#000000").drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

 button.hitArea = shape;
```

Comment: Note that fills and strokes are necessary (and not used) for masks. They are handy to use so you can add your mask to the stage to preview it.